# How many FFMPEG commands can I run on a machine

Tags: ffmpeg, stream

Assuming that I have a machine that has the specifications listed below, how many ffmpeg commands (that are taking video from IP camera and encoding it for further stream) could be running at the same time:

- i7 9th gen
- 16 Gb of RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

What is the resource takeup for each command like that.

Example of one of the commands I am running could is below.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://ipaddress:port/profile" -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://ipaddress:port/destination/application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on so many factors. No one can answer you precisely. We don't know the format of the input, it's codec, it's framerate etc. We don't know your FFmpeg version, we don't know your OS, if your PC is overclocked or dirty.
Anyways, we probably can't give you any number, you will be better off trying it yourself.
Try to monitor such command on your machine with `htop` on a linux or directly with the task manager on windows.
Extrapolate from this data, but even with that you won't be able to account for everyth